# PHP Saving Dynamic Radioboxes

Tags: php

Im having trouble tring to figure out how to save dynamic radio buttons.

I have a project where i have to use radiobuttons instead of checkboxes.

Basically, there is a database table with "roles" in it ... i.e administrator, user, etc etc etc and these are updateable but the user.

On a specific page, these get spit out with a radio button next to them, like so:

```
<input name="wfa" type="radio" id="wfa" class="radio" value="1" /><label for="wfa">administrator</label>
```

These go on down the page, for as many entries there are in the database.

What i need to do is save the checked ones to the database, but being dynamic i cant save each value to a individual row ..... any help?

Someone mentioned serialize, i had a look at the php documentation but it didnt make much sense to me.

Cheers.

Comment: Off topic: You are aware of `<label><input name="wfa" type="radio" class="radio" value="1" />administrator</label>`, right? (Given that you don't need the ID anywhere else.)

Comment: Could you elaborate why you can't store each value in individual roles? I would suggest that as the most flexible solution?

Answer (score 1):

You would normally have (at least) three database tables: `users`, `roles`, and `users_roles` (a look-up table). The `users` table and `roles` table are self-explanatory. The `users_roles` table would probably have two columns: `user_id` and `role_id`.

So for example, they would look similar to as follows:

```
Table: users
id INT PRIMARY KEY
username VARCHAR
password VARCHAR
...

Table: roles
id INT PRIMARY KEY
name VARCHAR

Table: users_roles
user_id INT
role_id INT
```

With this database structure, you can then find out what roles a user has with a query like the following:

```
SELECT
    r.*
FROM
    users u, roles r, users_roles ur
WHERE
    u.id = ur.user_id
AND
    r.id = ur.role_id
```

This will then give you an array of roles assigned to the current user ID, which you can loop over and output a check box (a better solution in my opinion).

```
$res = mysql_query($sql);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($res)) {
    printf('<label for="role_%d">%s</label>', $row->id, $row->name);
    printf('<input type="checkbox" name="role[]" value="%1$d" id="role_%1$d" />', $row->id);
}
```

When you submit this, the checked check boxes will then be available as an array under `$_POST['roles']`, which you can loop over and insert into the `users_roles` table.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the code, but im fine with printing them out ... basically all i need help with is how to store them if they are dynamic ... and also, they need to be radiobuttons with individual names, like my example at the top

Comment: Yes, and they do. They'd be stored in the `roles` table. But each user could have multiple roles then. And I mention how to save them in my last paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

> What i need to do is save the checked ones to the database, but being dynamic i cant save each value to a individual row ..... any help?

Why can't you maintain a reference table between `roles` and `users` with `user_id` and `role_id`? (Let's call this table `users_roles_mm`.)

When the form is submitted, delete all rows for the current user (`user_id`) and insert a row with a `(user_id, role_id)` pair for each checked input (role).

The idea here is that each table—`roles` and `users`—are dynamic, as is the reference between them. I.e., `users_roles_mm` is highly dynamic since it depends neither on the structure of the `users` table nor the `roles` table.

Comment: I am unaware of how many radio buttons there will be, there might be 10, there might be 100 ... i need a way of saving them and getting them back out of the database

Comment: @Chris Yes, and that's exactly what's possible with a [normalized](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) structure. To read out the roles you just `JOIN` over the reference table.

Comment: Look at my answer and combine it with this answer. The values of your buttons are the record ID. You will have all the IDs in the post array and that's how you will query your db again.